Can't get facebook prophet to work - The procedure entry point ... could not be located in the dynamic link library
I'm trying to use facebook but when I run fit on it I get the following error pop up

as well as the following errors in my console
C:\Users\natha\prophet_env\Lib\site-packages\prophet\forecaster.py:1133: UserWarning: Could not infer format, so each element will be parsed individually, falling back to `dateutil`. To ensure parsing is consistent and as-expected, please specify a format.
  self.history_dates = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df['ds'].unique(), name='ds')).sort_values()
C:\Users\natha\prophet_env\Lib\site-packages\prophet\forecaster.py:287: UserWarning: Could not infer format, so each element will be parsed individually, falling back to `dateutil`. To ensure parsing is consistent and as-expected, please specify a format.
  df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])
15:15:46 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] start processing
15:16:48 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] done processing
15:16:48 - cmdstanpy - ERROR - Chain [1] error: terminated by signal 3221225657
Optimization terminated abnormally. Falling back to Newton.
15:16:48 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] start processing
15:16:49 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] done processing
15:16:49 - cmdstanpy - ERROR - Chain [1] error: terminated by signal 3221225657
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\natha\prophet_env\Lib\site-packages\prophet\models.py", line 121, in fit
    self.stan_fit = self.model.optimize(**args)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\natha\prophet_env\Lib\site-packages\cmdstanpy\model.py", line 659, in optimize
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Error during optimization! Command 'C:\Users\natha\prophet_env\Lib\site-packages\prophet\stan_model\prophet_model.bin random seed=2958 data file=C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpliht0_s6\j_l454ns.json init=C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpliht0_s6\m4_zt8i8.json output file=C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpliht0_s6\prophet_modelzksydstr\prophet_model-20241026151546.csv method=optimize algorithm=lbfgs iter=10000' failed:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\natha\My Drive\Math PhD\Research\Signal Recovery\Code\SignalRecovery2024\MissingValuesProphetShare.py", line 46, in prophet_to_h_data
    y_hat_array = run_prophet(train_df, test_df)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\natha\My Drive\Math PhD\Research\Signal Recovery\Code\SignalRecovery2024\MissingValuesProphetShare.py", line 10, in run_prophet
    m.fit(train)
  File "C:\Users\natha\prophet_env\Lib\site-packages\prophet\forecaster.py", line 1232, in fit
    self.params = self.stan_backend.fit(stan_init, dat, **kwargs)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\natha\prophet_env\Lib\site-packages\prophet\models.py", line 128, in fit
    self.stan_fit = self.model.optimize(**args)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\natha\prophet_env\Lib\site-packages\cmdstanpy\model.py", line 659, in optimize
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Error during optimization! Command 'C:\Users\natha\prophet_env\Lib\site-packages\prophet\stan_model\prophet_model.bin random seed=82852 data file=C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpliht0_s6\ftx8ntg6.json init=C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpliht0_s6\drb948rp.json output file=C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpliht0_s6\prophet_model7qxhitzb\prophet_model-20241026151648.csv method=optimize algorithm=newton iter=10000' failed:

I've tried running cmdstanpy.install_cmdstan, changing model.py, and making a new venv as suggested here and in other places, but I can't get it to work. Google searches come back with basically the same suggestions. Does anyone know if there is a better resolution?
